# How can I copy all line of a notepad file that contain a specific word?

Tags: notepad

I have a large notepad TSV file that I need to copy all lines that contain a specific word in them and then paste them into an excel file. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

1. Use Notepad++
2. `Ctrl+F` to bring up the search box, then go to the Mark tab. Enter your keyword, and tick 'Bookmark line'. Now click Mark All.

[image]

3. Now you have a bunch of lines with a blue dot in the left border

[image]

4. Now click 'Search' on the top toolbar > Bookmark > Copy Bookmarked Lines

[image]

5. Paste the results into Excel

[image]

Comment: You should use word boundaries to avoid matching `myKeyword` or `Keywords`

Comment: Simple question gets a simple answer.